# adding values to listView

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to populate a `ListView`....but I cant add 2 string values from database used in `SimpleCursorAdapter`....
Any one, help me

Code

ListView.java

```
public class ListView extends ListActivity {

SQLiteDatabase messagedb;
List<String> senderArray = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> bodyArray = new ArrayList<String>();

String[] simpleSenderArray = new String[ senderArray.size() ];

String[] simpleBodyArray = new String[ bodyArray.size() ];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_list);

    senderArray.toArray( simpleSenderArray );
    bodyArray.toArray( simpleBodyArray );

    messagedb=ListView.this.openOrCreateDatabase("message",0, null);

            //This database created already and add sender and body values...here just open that database
    Cursor  cur=messagedb.rawQuery("select sender, body from tab2", null);
    while(cur.moveToNext())
    {
        String sender = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("sender"));
        String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("body"));
        senderArray.add(sender);
        bodyArray.add(body);
    }
    cur.close();


    messagedb.close();

     int[] to = new int[] { R.id.sender_entry, R.id.body_entry };

     SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.my_list_entry, cur,simpleSenderArray, to);

     this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);


}

}
```

my_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ListView

    android:id="@android:id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

my_list_entry.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sender_entry"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="28dip" />
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/body_entry"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="28dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Can somebody help me to populate my `ListView`?

Comment: I see that you create a table here: `messagedb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tab2(sender INT(13),body varchar)");` But have you added any rows to you database?

Comment: this database created already and add sender and body values...here just open that database

Comment: this database created already and add sender and body values...here just open that database.........any idea?

Comment: Are you sure your cursor isn't empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have named your Activity `ListView` which is already a built-in class name, I highly recommend changing it to something unique to prevent any confusion or naming conflicts.

In your SQLite table, you ought to have an `_id INTEGER` column set as the `PRIMARY KEY`, Android requires this `_id` column to bind the data to any ListView, Spinner, etc. (Technically SQLite3 creates a column like this automatically, but I believe it is best to define it yourself.)

```
    messagedb.execSQL(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tab2(" +
        " _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
        " sender INT(13)," +
        " body varchar)");
```

Your code should look more like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_list);

    // Using a SQLiteOpenHelper might be best, but I'll assume that this command works
    messagedb=ListView.this.openOrCreateDatabase("message",0, null);

    Cursor cur = messagedb.rawQuery("select _id, sender, body from tab2", null);
    String[] from = new String[] { "_id", "sender", "body" }
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.sender_entry, R.id.body_entry };

    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.my_list_entry, cur, from, to);

    this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

You might want to consider using the SQLiteDatabase.query() methods, I believe it is a touch faster:

```
Cursor cur = messagedb.query("tab2", new String[] {"_id", "sender", "body"}, null, null, null, null, null);
```

I also recommend defining static variables for all you column names for future ease-of-coding.

Lastly, this should work for a table without the _id column, but again I don't recommend it:

```
Cursor cur = messagedb.rawQuery("select rowid as _id, sender, body from tab2", null);
```

Comment: @Dipin.K.G I didn't think it would be perfect, but I'll need some information to help you. Please add the LogCat errors and the code you are currently using to your question.

Comment: How can i open this Body message while i am clicking the items on list view

Comment: and also how can i add date and time also adding in this list as receiving date and time

Comment: Use an [OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) to catch which row the user clicks, use the row's `_id` inside this listener to open the Body of the message. (But where do you want to open it: in a new Activity, a dialog, a TextView?)

Comment: You can add a time column to your database, like this: `time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT current_timestamp`. `DEFAULT current_timestamp` means if you this column is null when you insert a row, the database will automatically set time to the date/time at that moment.

Comment: where do you  open it: in a new Activity, a dialog, a TextView? what is better

Comment: If the message has the potential be long, edited, or forwarded I would recommend a new Activity. Otherwise, it's a graphical design preference.

Comment: sam can u answer my question in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295534/block-my-outgoing-call-and-launch-an-activity-for-that-specified-time)

Comment: dynamically generated textView in that activity?